# What is this potted house plant with large, stiff, veined leaves?

Tags: houseplants

What is this potted house plant with large, stiff, veined green leaves?

[image]

Comment: Please post some photos

Answer (score 1):

I believe that hadsome plant is a *ficus*.  To guess further, a *[Ficus benghalensis](https://www.feedipedia.org/node/155)* (Banyan Fig).

> The trunk is massive, fluted. The bark is smooth, softly puberulous
> when young. The leaves are large, 8-25 cm long x 6-20 cm broad,
> stoutly petiolated. The lamina is coriaceous, nerved, ovate to obovate
> in shape. The lamina is glabrous on the upper face and finely
> pubescent beneath.

*Flora of Pakistan, 2020. Ficus benghalensis. Tropicos.org. Missouri Botanical Garden. USA* via *Feedpedia*

Are your plant's leaves leathery (coriaceous) near the edges, shinny on top and softly hairy on the bottom and petiole (leaf's stalk)?  Is the bark smooth?